# What does this do in Reactjs ====> <void, Props, void>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
export class HomeView extends React.Component<void, Props, void>
```

is the code I am trying to understand.

it is from, 
https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit/blob/master/src/views/HomeView/HomeView.js#L24

Comment: Whenever you see `/* @flow */` at the top of a file, that means that they are using the `Flow` static type checker created by Facebook. You can learn more about it [here](http://flowtype.org/).

Comment: Ahhh, silly silly me, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Thank you for the question and comment. I can understand from the @saadq comment it is based on flow. But I couldn't catch the why we select void, Props, and void are here. Is there any other rule behind it?